# Vagrant and VirtualBox suddenly don’t work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, crash, vagrant

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 I can no longer run VirtualBox (and hence Vagrant). Running any vagrant command results in:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:293:in `read': Input/output error @ rb_sysopen - /home/sillyinventor/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index (Errno::EIO)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:293:in `read'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:293:in `unlocked_reload'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:53:in `block in initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:323:in `block in with_index_lock'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:321:in `with_index_lock'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine_index.rb:52:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:637:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:637:in `machine_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:180:in `block in action_runner'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:439:in `hook'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:688:in `unload'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:176:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:176:in `<main>'
```

Running VirtualBox from command line results in a complete system lockup at waiting for power on (including sys rq). You can’t run VirtualBox from TTY for obvious reasons, and the lockup forces a hard shutdown (so no log).

I have checked the BIOS, and virtualization is enabled. There is plenty of harddrive space. I have uninstalled and reinstalled (in case there is a corrupt file). I have checked the syslog, but at the time where it crashed there are only bad characters. I have checked hard drive quality with smart control, and all seems well. The ~/.vagrant.ddata/machine-index/index file seems to be strangely unreadable.

I did install updates (`apt-get update` and `dist-upgrade`), may be related to that. Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Not useful info to me, but perhaps it'll mean something to you that it just prints the box character (missing value) repeatedly.

Comment: ... that seems very improbable to me. However, I will run some tests.

Comment: Yeah, the system is fine.

Comment: Hmm, I get an I/O error on viewing it, which is strange since the virtualbox is what crashes the computer... perhaps it's attempting to write there when it crashes?

Comment: VirtualBox had a new release on Jan 15; have you considered downgrading just VirtualBox? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog (Vagrant was last updated on Nov 2 which was longer ago, hence my suggestion to focus on VirtualBox. https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/releases)

Comment: does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472883/550907

Comment: No, it didn't. I will try reinstalling Ubuntu when I have the time and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `~/.vagrant.d/` and now it works.